# Why query doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix-3

I have fetched records from database using this query which works fine.

```
var SelectEmpInfo = "SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE emp_id ='"+empID+"'";

var SelectedEmpInfo = db.QuerySingle(SelectEmpInfo);
```

After that I want to update this record by applying the snap of code

```
if(SelectedEmpInfo != null)
{
    status = SelectedEmpInfo.status;
}

if(IsPost)
{
    var updateStatus = "UPDATE emp_info SET status='"+status+"' WHERE emp_id='"+empID+"'";
    db.Execute(updateStatus);   
    <h1>Successfully Updated</h1> 
}
```

If I remove the query from if block and put outside it than it works when page gets loaded but I don't want to do so.

The reason to place this code inside an if is that, query should only perform when button is pressed.

Please someone help me out here.

Kind regard

Radhesham

Comment: this does not appear to be the proper code at all. please post the PROPER FULL CODE of interest.

Comment: give me your email so that i can send you whole page for better way to guide me

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: You mean i should use like this:

var SelectEmpInfo = "SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE emp_id =@0'";
         var SelectedEmpInfo = db.QuerySingle(SelectEmpInfo);
But it still dont work

Comment: What is `IsPost`? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your time and concerns.
It was actually SQL injection problem and i found the answer of it here at mikes site
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/113/preventing-sql-injection-in-asp-net